# How can we overcome this improper result of pastespecial(xlPasteFormulas)?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I'm a newbie in VBA.
It would be really appreciated if you guys help me. Thanks you a lot, in advance.
The capture image of result is below.

[image: Result of PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas]

What I wanted to do is just to copy the formula written in the cell "A46", and then paste it in the cell "A47", and make sure that pasted formula is re-evaluated about its new location.

So I wrote code like below:

Worksheets("...").Range(Cells(46,1).Address).Copy
Worksheets("...").Range(Cells(47,1).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

However, it did not work properly as seen in the picture above.
The problems are, firstly, the pasted formula was not re-evaluated about its new location, specifically, to the row direction. As in the attached picture, it quotes the very adjacent cell in the column direction(:A46), however, not in the row direction(:B47). So it showed just value error.

Further, the 47th row became a kind of the first row of the table, it suddenly got some filter signs, and bold fonts as the headlines of table do.

How can I solve this improper result of pastespecial?

Thanks for reading this a bit long article.

Comment: instead of using copy and paste, I find it more efficient to just transfer the value between two ranges/cells. EX: .range("A1").value = .range("B1").value

Comment: Maybe you tried to replace the formulas or values of the footer?

Comment: What is the formula in A46?

Comment: Side note, but probably better to use `EOMONTH` to generate the next month, instead of just adding 31 days.

Comment: What is the exact formula in A46. Also is that Datavalidation in A47?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention. The formula in A46 is like this: IF([@터키]="","",31+A45) at which [@터키] means the column B.